# Custom user credentials for Nexmo / Vonage in Laravel notification

Tags: laravel, notifications, vonage

I'm writing a Laravel SMS notification with Nexmo channel. I don't want to use global API key but a different user-specific API key / secret instead. I tried to do it this way:

```php
class MyNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        $channels = ['mail'];

        if ($notifiable instanceof User) {
            if ($notifiable->sms_notifications && $notifiable->nexmo_api_key) {
                $channels[] = 'nexmo';
            }
        }

        return $channels;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
        /** @var User $notifiable */
        $nexmoClient = new Client(new Basic($notifiable->nexmo_api_key, $notifiable->nexmo_api_secret));

        return (new NexmoMessage())
            ->content("Test")
            ->usingClient($nexmoClient); // Ignored?
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and the client set by `->usingClient` seems to be ignored. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: A quick look over the source code shows that an SMS should be using either the supplied client or falling back to global, but the Shortcode handler doesn't. Are you sending using a full telephone number or a short code?

Comment: Full telephone number.